# Powershell - Getting multiple values from a nested object

Tags: json, git, rest, powershell, tfs

I am sure this is a very basic PowerShell question but I have a JSON file that I am loading into a PowerShell custom object with `ConvertFrom-Json` and the following `select-object` works

```
$JsonContent.value | Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name = 'commit'; Expression = { $_.commit.author.date }}
```

I am trying to get another column in the nested commit object and the following is NOT working so am hoping someone can help me figure out how to get a second value from the nested commit object (I have tried a few variations but not working)

```
JsonContent.value | Select-Object -Property Name, @{Name = 'commit'; Expression = { $_.commit.author.date}, {$_.commit.commitId}}
```

Thanks

Scott

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part after `Expression = ...` is a script block containing code so if you want to return an array of values there for being the value for the property `commit` then just modify

```
Expression = { $_.commit.author.date}, {$_.commit.commitId}
```

to

```
Expression = { $_.commit.author.date, $_.commit.commitId}
```

so that you use the commma operator to create and return your 2-element array

---

Probably you rather want to make some nice string representing the commit e.g.

```
Expression = { "{0} - {1}" -f $_.commit.author.date, $_.commit.commitId }
```

---

In case you want the `commitId` in a completely different column just add another property like so

```
... -Property Name, @{Name = 'commit'; Expression = { $_.commit.author.date}}, @{Name = 'commitId'; Expression = {$_.commit.commitId}}
```

Comment: I did get that to work before but it returns it like you said in a single column array with both values.  The two columns in my original select has name and commit.  Is there a way to get it into its own column so I can have a name, commit, and commitID column?

For example, is it possible to have a another name/expression in the select-object?

Comment: Thanks, that worked great - not sure how I missed that variation as I was trying so many

Comment: Related question - how can I use the where clause on the date?  I tried a few variations of this
| where-object ($_.commit.author.date -lt "2016-08-10") 

Also, how can I iterate through this object?  can I do a foreach and how would I access each column of data?

Comment: Well you can use `Where-Object` as usual but notice that the date in this case is a string so you may first want to convert it to `datetime`. Regarding how to access all properties of an  object dynamically you may want to have a look at `Get-Member`

Comment: can you provide some help/sample for both where-object and get-member on how to use them?